# How to concat columns of similar dataframes with new names

Tags: python, dataframe

I have two dataframes with similar columns:

```
df1 = (a, b, c, d)
df2 = (a, b, c, d)
```

I want `concat` or `merge` some columns of them like below in `df3`

```
   df3 = (a_1, a_2, b_1, b_2)
```

How can I put them beside as they are (without any change), and how can I merge them on a similar key like `d`? I tried to add them to a list and concat them but don't know how to give them a new name. I don't want multi-level column names.

```
   for ii, tdf in enumerate(mydfs):
       tdf = tdf.sort_values(by="fid", ascending=False)
        for _col in ["fid", "pred_text1"]:
            new_col = _col + str(ii)
            dfs.append(tdf[_col])
        ii += 1
    df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Comment: @Chris Thanks, no! The merge add them levels to columns, and I specified I don't like that way, just new names for columns.

Comment: Why don't you just use `merge` and then trying the `rename` function on the merged dataframe?

Comment: @AmirhosseinKiani I put more code, how can I rename `_col` to `new_col` in the loop

Comment: You used words `concat` and `merge` both in your question. From what I know, `concat` is usually used to join two dataframe, while `merge` is to compare two dataframes, and attach them to each other based on the similar labels. Which one do you want?

Comment: @AmirhosseinKiani if I could do both, it was better, `merge` is my priority! however if I want to cmpare them based on the sorted columns, then concat is better.

Comment: Create a multi index then merge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having a look at your dataframe, it would not be easy, but I am generating a dataframe to give you samples  and insight into how the code works:

```py
import pandas as pd
import re
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,4], "b":[2,4,5], "c":[5,6,7], "d":[1,2,3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"a":[6,7,5], "b":[3,4,8], "c":[6,3,9], "d":[1,2,3]})
mergedDf = df1.merge(df2, how="left", on="d").rename(columns=lambda x: re.sub("(.+)\_x", r"\1_1", x)).rename(columns=lambda x: re.sub("(.+)\_y", r"\1_2", x))
mergedDf
```

which results in:

|  | a_1 | b_1 | c_1 | d | a_2 | b_2 | c_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 5 | 1 | 6 | 3 | 6 |
| 1 | 2 | 4 | 6 | 2 | 7 | 4 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 | 5 | 7 | 3 | 5 | 8 | 9 |

If you are interested in dropping other columns you can use code below:

```py
mergedDf.iloc[:, ~mergedDf.columns.str.startswith("c")]
```

which results in:

|  | a_1 | b_1 | d | a_2 | b_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 6 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 4 | 2 | 7 | 4 |
| 2 | 4 | 5 | 3 | 5 | 8 |